# Как завершить все функции кроме одной?

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу телеграм бота, мне нужно чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на кнопку "Меню" то все функции "def" кроме функции "Меню" завершались, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

вызывайте каждую функцыю в процессе, а при вызове меню завершайте все процессы и затем создавайте новый процесс. Примерно так:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def menu():
    for i in multiprocessing.active_children():
        i.kill()
    #doing menu staf
    pass

def other_funk():
    # doing oher staff
    pass

other = Process(target=other_funk)
other.start()
#doing what u want while other process works
menu()#kiling all other processes first
```